# Importing osgeo library in python fails

Tags: python, docker, conda, poppler, osgeo

I am having trouble importing the osgeo library in my python application. I am working in a conda environment defined by the following dependencies:

For default channel:

```
python=3.6.0
pandas=0.19.2
scikit-learn=0.18.1
numpy=1.12.1
requests=2.14.2
pyyaml=3.12
jinja2=2.9.6
```

For the forge channel:

```
gdal=2.2.1
```

Installed with pip:

```
jellyfish
unidecode
scikit-optimize
skater==1.0.2
boto3==1.4.1
schedule==0.4.3
geopy==1.11.0
fuzzywuzzy==0.15.1
python-Levenshtein==0.12.0
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
from osgeo import ogr
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
_gdal = swig_import_helper()
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
ImportError: libpoppler.so.66: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have also tried to add the poppler dependence in forge channel, but it won't work.

Do you have any idea to solve this? A solution based only in modifying the conda environment is prefered, but since I am working with Docker, it wouldn't be a problem to change anything else in my environment.

My application was working fine until today, so I suppose the problem is related to some change in the chain of dependencies, but I can't figure out what is happening.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: The solution was to change the gdal version to a higher one (once it was released). I think there was some kind of problem with that version that was fixed a few days after

Comment: I actually did use the newest gdal version so I think it was a bug. I'm guessing that it's fixed by now though. However I managed to get a working installation using Synaptic Package Manager instead, so no worries.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a problem with a conda-forge package, it's helpful to check when the package was built, for example:
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gdal/files

If your package was just built, it could be that the dependencies are still building, since the CI building process for `conda-forge` takes time.

It could also be that looking at that list of files on anaconda.org, you find another more recent, slightly different gdal version that could work with your environment.

Also note that when using multiple channels (e.g. `defaults` and `conda-forge`) there are issues you should be aware of:
https://conda-forge.org/docs/conda-forge_gotchas.html#using-multiple-channels